# how to add temp column in mysql table which contains max value of a respective group

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, rdbms

I want to do something Like this :

Current table :

| Name | coupon_price |
| --- | --- |
| John | 10 |
| Sammy | 20 |
| Ben | 100 |
| Joseph | 120 |
| John | 90 |
| Joseph | 20 |
| John | 50 |
| Sammy | 30 |

while selecting data in query (Sum of Coupon price for each customer)
without loosing the actual rows of customers, i want to have this expected result :

| Name | coupon_price | total_coupon_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 150 |
| Sammy | 20 | 50 |
| Ben | 100 | 100 |
| Joseph | 120 | 140 |
| John | 90 | 150 |
| Joseph | 20 | 140 |
| John | 50 | 150 |
| Sammy | 30 | 50 |

Goal is to select the sum of coupon prices for distinct customer, not alter the rows so we cannot use group by in main query, also the total coupon price should be same for all similar names.

Edit : I don't want to modify the table, I want this column while running select query, run time temp column.

Comment: Not clear - Show samples of what you wa,t (different cases)

Comment: Hello @Dri372, the first table is the actual table, and while fetching the data, I want the third column which will have sum of coupon_price for each customer, like John has total 3 entries, 10, 90 and 50, so (10+90+50) 150 should be in all rows where the name is John.

Comment: Ok I did not understood that your second example was you expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Name,
       coupon_price,
       total_coupon_amount 
FROM t1 
JOIN (SELECT Name, 
             SUM(coupon_price) AS total_coupon_amount 
      FROM t1 
      GROUP BY Name) r2 USING (Name);
```

You create the sum in a subquery and join the two.

You should/could put also at the `ORDER BY` what you want

If you want a view just out `CREATE VIEW` before

Comment: It worked exactly how I wanted, except I din't want to sort the data with Name. Thank you so much !

Comment: A good practice in db design is to have a first filed 'id' (int or bigint)  in every tables. With it you can easily redo the 'iniial order' of the table you want when/where you want.
If you want to create it 'dynamicaly', you can use : set @id=0; and in you select @id:=@id+1

Comment: now I am unable to filter this column, I want to filter those rows where coupon_price is less than 50 and total_coupon_amount is greater than 100, as the having clause doesn't directly work inside where.

Comment: Reread my last sentence (CREATE VIEW) and than you'll be able to do everything like with a table.